# How to call a jquery function inside template (type="text/x-tmpl") jquery?

Tags: jquery, templates

Hi all i am working on jquery i need to call a function in ('text/x-tmpl') template i have this 
 I am trying to run this javascript code, it doesnt work, wht is the process make it run
 is there any body please help

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">

     checkbox();

{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}    
    <ul class="template-upload fade imagePeiview">

        <li class="preview"><span class="fade image-gallery-thumb"></span></li>
        <li class="name"><span class="imgname">{%=file.name%}</span> </li>
        <li class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></li>


        <li class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button style="display:none" class="btn btn-info">

                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</li>
    </ul>
{% } %}
</script> 



<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        function checkbox() {
            alert(1);
        }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading this template via Ajax then you can call required JavaScript function on Success handler of your template load Ajax, which means that you are waiting for loading of your template and then calling JS function present on that template

Comment: thanks for reply visualizer yes but i had tried but it dosen't work could u please provide some piece of code for it